Get model relationship collection from another database in Laravel
I have set the connection to two databases properly. I also have created eloquent table models and I can query a single table relationship from another database easily e.g.
$user->customer

User model
class User extends Model
{
  protected $connection = 'mysql';
  protected $table = 'users';
  
  
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Customer::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

}

Customer model
class Customer extends Model
{
  protected $connection = 'second_db';
  protected $table = 'customers';
  
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'customer_id', 'id');
    }
}

I can get the orders data in the second database using this simple query
$customer->order

But it give an empty result when querying from the first database using
$user->customer->order

or 

$user->customer()->order

How to get the relationship data in the second dB by querying from the first dB?

You probably need to remove the() from the query and separate the load into separate statements. When you chain the statements like that, it's going to create child queries using the same connection.

I can query it using this relation in customer model. but it is not what I am looking for. I need something more robust and efficient. public function order($id)   {     return DB::connection('second_db')->table('orders')->where('customer_id', $id)->get();   }  and query   $customer->order($customer->id)->toArray();

I got it. I just need to define all necessary models connected to second dB, then I can make any long relationship as I want efficiently.

what you might want is HasManyThrough, so user -> order going thru customer. You can try this by checking out docs: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

I just read the docs. this also works for Laravel 8 and 9. thanks!

Based on the requirements of OP and checking out the description in docs, you might want to try HasManyThrough method:
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the orders for the user.
     */
    public function orders(): HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Orders::class, Customer::class);
    }
}


// String based syntax...
return $user->through('customers')->has('orders');
 
// Dynamic syntax...
return $user->throughCustomers()->hasOrders();


Just to clarify. it uses the relation names, not the table names.

You might need to specify the connection inside the underlying Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder object when eager loading.
$customers = Customer::query()
    ->with([
        'order' => function (HasMany $relation) {
            $eloquentBuilder = $relation->getQuery();
            $baseBuilder = $eloquentBuilder->getQuery();
            $baseBuilder->connection = DB::connection('mysql');
        },
    ])
    ->get();

Applying this to a nested relationship:
$user = User::query()
    ->with(['customers' => function (HasMany $customers_relation) {
        $customers_relation
            ->getQuery()
            ->getQuery()
            ->connection = DB::connection('second_db');

        $customers_relation->with(['orders' => function (HasMany $orders_relation) {
            $orders_relation
                ->getQuery()
                ->getQuery()
                ->connection = DB::connection('mysql');
        }]);
    }])
    ...
    ->first();


I think you make it too more complicated :D

The question remains: does it work? I only tested it for a hasmany relationship between mysql and sqlite locally.
